# How to get total objects and total storage of each folder on S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket named `camera-assets`, in that bucket I have a separate folder for each camera and each folder contains millions / billions of files.  I want to get a total number of files and storage of each folder in my bucket.

I tried following CLI command:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket camera-assets --prefix 1011-front-external/snapshots/ --output json --query "[sum(Contents[].Size), length(Contents[])]"
```

But failed to get the result because folder has million/billion of files. It works if there are only a few files.

Please help me to get files count and storage.

Answer (score 7):

AWS command line interface tool has `--summarize` option (have to use along with `--recursive`), which shows number of objects & total size:

```
$ aws s3 ls s3://camera-assets --summarize --recursive
   ...
Total Objects: xx
   Total Size: xx
```

Comment: doesn't `summarize` (and other ls arguments) work with the default `--page-size` value which is 1000 by default ? so if ops has more than 1k files in the folder, not sure it will work

Comment: May be its a bug or `--page-size` is meant for something else. On one of my test bucket there are more than 1000 files, it shows them fine in summary: `aws s3 ls s3://general-test-s3/ --summarize --recursive` ... `Total Objects: 1541`

Comment: If you have more than 1000 files use this: aws s3 ls s3://camera-assets --summarize --recursive --page-size 9999999

Comment: Max page size, also default page size, is 1000. You can put --page-size a billion all you want. The --recursive flag is what gets it to do paginated results and return a count when there are more than 1000 objects.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have a bucket with your amount of data to give a try but I found [s4cmd](https://github.com/bloomreach/s4cmd) to be quite good in the past

you can run commands as

```
$ s4cmd du s3://camera-assets
$ s4cmd du s3://camera-assets/1011-front-external/snapshots/
```

What you can do is also looking at [cloudwatch](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) - select the S3 metrics, for each bucket you have 2 metrics:
- NumberOfObjects
- NumberOfObjects

benefit is that you will see how it evolves over time - drawback is that its only at bucket level so you cannot get by folder level.